# Keep getting an error/crash due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've checked my connections and class names as all the other threads with this same issue suggest.

**Error message**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key parksTableView.'

**View controller where I get the crash**

```
import UIKit

class ParksViewController: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var parkNames = ["Sunnyside", "South Oak", "Tower", "Arno", "Arbor", "Holmes", "Brookside", "Brookside Tennis Courts", "Loose", "Gilham", "Brush Creek", "Westwood"]


@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var parksTableView: UITableView!

func viewDidLoad(){

self.parksTableView.delegate = self
self.parksTableView.dataSource = self


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return parkNames.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    print(indexPath.row)

    cell.textLabel?.text = parkNames[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Maybe I'm just not connecting the right things to the right places? I've tried a combination of different connections and have deleted and reconnected connections many times in order to try to fix this issue, but it I still can't understand what is wrong.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zskF.png)

[Connection Inspector of ParksViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo0Uw.png)

Comment: Can you post the storyboard outlets screenshot?

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Comment: Not this. Can you post `Connection Inspector`

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: Did you added `ParksViewController` as your custom class in the storyboard.

Comment: Yes. ParksViewController is my custom class in the storyboard.

Comment: Did you changed the `ParksViewController: UITableView` to `ParksViewController: UITableViewController`? After that clean the project and try to run.

Comment: It did not work. I tried deleting all my connections and re-connecitng them and now I am unable to set my outlets/the UITableView as a delegate/data source..

Comment: Means your custom class in storyboard is not correct.

Comment: Literally everything is named correctly. I was able to do it up until the point where I made the changes suggested in this thread and since every single thread about this issue that I could find on the internet talked about making sure the class is correct - that has been my main focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error, it says `<UIViewController 0x7fc416a04f80>`. You think you have a `ParksViewController` but you really just have a plain `UIViewController`.

Comment: So what exactly needs to be changed in order for it to be a ParksViewController as it is named and everything?